# Beautifull soup takes too much time for text extraction in common crawl data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, beautifulsoup, common-crawl

I have to parse html content in common crawl data-set (warc.gz files). I have decided to used `bs4` (Beautifulsoup) module as mostly people suggest it. Following is the code snippet to get text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(src, "lxml")
[x.extract() for x in soup.findAll(['script', 'style'])]
txt = soup.get_text().encode('utf8')
```

without `bs4`, one file is completely processed in 9 minutes (test case) but If I use `bs4` to parse text, then Job is finished in about 4 hours. What this is happening. Is there any better solution other than `bs4`? 
Note: bs4 is class that contains many modules like Beautifilsoup.

Comment: what do you mean 'without bs4'?

Comment: You can use `lxml` or `re` (regular expression) which will be faster than `bs4`

Comment: Any example for lxml or re that can remove html, script and styles tags?

Comment: Check the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the main time consuming part is the extracting of tags in the list compression. With `lxml` and python regular expression you can do it like the followings.

```
import re

script_pat = re.compile(r'<script.*?<\/script>')

# to find all scripts tags
script_pat.findall(src)

# do your stuff
print re.sub(script_pat, '', src)
```

Using `lxml` you can do it like this:

```
from lxml import html, tostring
et = html.fromstring(src)

# remove the tags
[x.drop_tag() for x in et.xpath('//script')]

# do your stuff
print tostring(et)
```